# Is this a lattice? X = {1,3,4,12}, Divisilibity relation.

Tags: lattice-orders

I am just starting to learn about lattices. I am trying to see what examples I can come up with. It is helpful if I can have some outside confirmation about my thinking.

Let $X = \{1,3,4,12\}$

Define poset $\{X,\mid\}$ where $\mid$ refers to divisibility. (So, $4\mid1$ but $1\nmid4.)$

I am under the impression that $X$ is a lattice. Divisibility makes $\wedge = gcd$ and $\vee = lcm$

In particular,

$$(1 \wedge 3) = 1 \in X$$

$$(1 \vee 3) = 3 \in X$$

$$(1 \wedge 4) = 1 \in X$$

$$(1 \vee 4) = 4 \in X$$

$$(1 \wedge 12) = 1 \in X$$

$$(1 \vee 12) = 12 \in X$$

$$(3 \wedge 4) = 1 \in X$$

$$(3 \vee 4) = 12 \in X$$

$$(3 \wedge 12) = 3 \in X$$

$$(3 \vee 12) = 12 \in X$$

$$(4 \wedge 12) = 4 \in X$$

$$(4 \vee 12) = 12 \in X$$

Sorry to just write out all the cases. A simple "Yes" or "No" with a brief explanation if No would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's exactly right... **for the opposite relation**, 
$$x \preceq y \iff x \text{ divides } y \text{.}$$
Note: standard usage is that "$x\mid y$ " means this relation "$x$ divides $y$", not "$x$ is divisible by $y$".

For $\preceq$ as above, $\wedge$ and $\vee$ are *gcd* and *lcm* respectively. Of course all your cases are correct.

*However*, the relation "is divisible by" is the reverse of $\preceq$:
$$
x \sqsubseteq y \iff y \preceq x
$$
so with respect to $\sqsubseteq$, meet and join are interchanged: $\wedge_{\sqsubseteq}$ is *lcm* and $\vee_{\sqsubseteq}$ is *gcd*.

If an ordering is a lattice ordering then so is its reverse.
If you confirm that an ordering is a lattice ordering (sup and inf exist for all pairs of elements), and then use $\wedge$ and $\vee$ to denote the sup and inf that you proved to exist, *then you don't have to prove that the lattice axioms hold for $\wedge$ and $\vee$: they do, by definition.* That's the case here.

Comment: I see, thank you very much. Fair to say that this is not a chain?

Comment: Very very fair to say that this is not a chain :) It's [Hasse diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasse_diagram) is a diamond. That's true for both "x divides y" and its reverse -- regardless of whether 1 or 12 is on top.

Comment: Removing 3, this is a chain, yes?

Comment: That's right. Remove 3, or remove 4, and it's a chain.

Comment: Beautiful, thank you very much.

Comment: You're welcome. Keep up the good work!

Answer (score 0):

Nothing at all wrong with writing out all the cases.  It's one of the clearer ways to do it in this case!

You'll also need to show that [the following laws hold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_(order)):

- commutative ($A \wedge B = B \wedge A$ and $A \vee B = B \vee A$)
- associative ($A \wedge (B \wedge C) = (A \wedge B) \wedge C$ and $A \vee (B \vee C) = (A \vee B) \vee C$)
- absorption ($A \wedge (A \vee B) = A$ and $A \vee (A \wedge B) = A$ )
- idempotent ($A \vee A = A$ and $A \wedge A = A$)

Comment: Thanks! I believe this is also not a chain, correct? Because $3 \nmid 4$ and $4 \nmid 3$?

Comment: The absorption laws are $A\wedge(A\vee B)$ and its dual, not what you have.

Comment: @BrianO whoops; too enthusiastic with CTRL-V. Fixed!